# How to wait until the file is downloaded (or URL is validated)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, async-await

I have a problem, I want to wait in the `Main()` until the `Download()` is finished. However, the file downloading/checking starts, at the same time the other lines start executing.

How can I use `await`or anything else to wait in the `Main`?

```
    private void Main()
    {
       Download("http://webserver/file.xml");
       //Do something here ONLY if the file exists!!
    }


    //This method invokes the URL validation
    private void Download(downloadURL)
    {
       System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri(downloadURL);
       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
       request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(WebRequestCallBack), request);
    }

    //In this method the URL is being checked for its validity
    void WebRequestCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebRequest resultInfo = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response;
        string statusCode;
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)resultInfo.EndGetResponse(result);
            statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            statusCode = e.Message;
        }
        onCompletion(statusCode);
    }

    //This method does not help! I just added if it could be any useful
    private  void onCompletion(string status)
    {
        if (status == HttpStatusCode.OK.ToString())
            MessageBox.Show("file exists");  
        else
            MessageBox.Show("file does not exists");  
    }
```

What I need, in detail is...

- Download a file from a given URL
- Before downloading verify the URL
- **if (verfied) then**

  - continue downloading and do other tasks
- **else**

  - fail and stop the process, Don't download! and give a message that URL was broken (couldn't verified)!

I am **trying to do the "Verification" part, checking if the URL is correct and waiting for response**. I need some kind of STATUS of the verification process, in order to continue.

Comment: Any reason `//Do something here ONLY if the file exists!!` couldn't be done in `WebRequestCallBack` or `onCompletion`?

Comment: .net 4.5 or an earlier version?

Comment: @Ginosaji well, I just put the example in simple form, It is not easily possible to use the `onCompletion`. I need continuity of the code.

Comment: @daryal earlier version .net 4.0

Comment: You must explain what do you need more detailed. Otherwise the answer is: "use synchronous version".

Comment: Your only options are to (1) put the code in the callback or (2) download the file synchronously. Option 1 would be the "correct" way, as option 2 would block the UI thread and make the application appear to freeze for the duration of the download.

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan: I have added some detail what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Should try:

```
var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse,  
                                               request.EndGetResponse, null);
var response = task.Result;
```

Comment: Thanks Cuong Le for replying, but there's no `request.GetResponse()` method available, at least not for WP7

Comment: Directly calling `BeginGetResponse()` and then `EndGetResponse()` would be much simpler.

Comment: I am using the above solution like... `Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

task.ContinueWith((t) =>
{
   WebResponse webResponse = t.Result;
   var response = (HttpWebResponse)webResponse;
   responseString = response.StatusCode.ToString();
});` ... I always get empty `responseString` and eventhough I am passing incorrect URL, it doesn't crash!  Not working as yet! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ManualResetEventSlim object. Initialize it to true when you instantiate it. At the end of OnComplete method call the Reset method on the ManualResetEventSlim  object. In your main application, you just have to invoke the WaitOne method on the ManualResetEventSlim  object.

Comment: This is what he wants but not what he needs. The OP shouldn't use async IO just to wait for completion.